ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application not loading styles from styles.css file
I’m working on an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application using Visual Studio. I've set up my project with a styles.css file in the wwwroot/css directory. However, the styles are not being applied when I run the application. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Correctly Linking the CSS File: I made sure that the  tag in _Layout.cshtml is pointing to the correct path:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/styles.css" /> e

nsuring Static Files are Served: I confirmed that app.UseStaticFiles(); is included in the Program.cs file:
app.UseStaticFiles();

Attempted Direct Access to the CSS File: I tried loading the CSS file directly by navigating to http://localhost:5070/css/styles.css in my browser, but it doesn't seem to load.
Tested with Inline Styles: I used an inline  tag in _Layout.cshtml as a test:
<style>
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

Even this is not applied, suggesting that something is preventing the styles from being rendered.
Checked Developer Tools: I have checked the browser’s developer console and network tab, but I’m not seeing any errors related to the CSS file.
Additional Information:
The application is running on http://localhost:5070.
The styles.css file is correctly located at wwwroot/css/styles.css.
The project is configured with Razor Pages and uses the default middleware setup.

Hi Rhichyllie, if you are debugging the project in vs2022, please navtigate to project and find bin\Debug\net8.0 folder and check if the styles.css file exist or not under the wwwroot/css.

If not, we should include all the files(under wwwroot)  during the deployment.

the in-line style is probably being over-ridden by webkit/bootstrap so that's a bit of a red-herring.
